# Python functions issue

Tags: python, function

I wrote two functions. First one, when called checks if the number is three-digit, and second one is checking if the number is even or odd:

```
def even(n):
    if n%2==0:
        print('number {} is even'.format(n))
    else:
        print('number {} is not even'.format(n))
        return

def main(n):
    kraj=True
    while(kraj):
        a=int(input('three-digit number pls: '))
        if (a>99 and a<1000):
            kraj=False
            return True
        else:
            print('I said three-digit number!! ::')
            return False
main(0)
```

What my problem is, when I call function `even` like `even(a)`, it gives me an error saying `a` is not defined.

Comment: Where is the indentation?!

Comment: What is your *complete* error when calling `even(a)` ? Are you calling it when `a` is defined ? Does `even(1); even(2)` works ?

Comment: Where do you call the even() function?

Comment: three-digit number pls: 111
>>> even(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    even(a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: I'm sorry, first time using the website im kinda clungy... and I'm really new to the python so...pardon for all mistakes

Comment: @JurajPavlovich - You need to put `111` into a variable first and pass it or pass `111` directly to the function with `even(111)`

Comment: Rewrite your question from the ground up using all the advice given to you in all the comments in order to reopen your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return `a` in the `main()` function and pass it to the `even` function.

```
def main(n):
    kraj=True
    while(kraj):
        a=int(input('three-digit number pls: '))
        if (a>99 and a<1000):
            kraj=False
            return a
        else:
            print('I said three-digit number!! ::')
            return False

a = main(0)
even(a)
```

Comment: Oh great! simple and effective :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to return the value of a so you can use it somewhere else
2. Also you have a `while` and return in if and else.
   Therefore you do not need your while loop. Or you want the user to reenter on error you then have to get rid of the `return` in else
3. You should give your function a more meaningfull name like `read_threedigit_number`
4. You normally don't put paranthesis around `if` and `while`

**Improved Code**

```
def read_threedigit_number(n):
    while True:
        a=int(input('three-digit number pls: '))
        if a>99 and a<1000:
            return a
        else:
            print('I said three-digit number!')


a = read_threedigit_number(0)
even(a)
```

Comment: Yes that's cool dude, the issue is i have to re-enter the number once its not three-digit, that's why "while" was there
But I inderstand now about defining function in other than main..for more uses thanks